# Cant get a while loop to work the way that I'm intending

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

I'm doing an exercise to create a rock, paper scissors game.

I'm trying to go a bit beyond what the exercise requires by setting up how many times players can play the game. The players can choose how many hands they want to play at the beginning of the game.

The thing is that so far I have never combined While Loops with a Function, and I'm having problems with this, I was hoping someone could help me figure this out and show me where I'm wrong.

On a separate note, I feel like my code is getting too long, any suggestions on how to minimize it?

Update 1
I got it to work by moving the while loop from before the function and applying it to last section, like this:
But now im trying to print a message at the end with the player scores, however, Python is not recognizing the player_1_scroe variable beaches is inside of the function. How would you solve this proble?

```
player_1 = input("Enter player 1 Name: ").capitalize()
player_2 = input("Enter player 2 Name: ").capitalize()
game_limit = int(input("Enter how many hands you want to play"))
play_count = 0


def play(usr1, usr2):
    player_1_points = 0
    player_2_points = 0

    if usr1 == usr2:
        player_1_points += 1
        player_2_points += 1
        return "Its a Tie!"

    elif usr1 == "r":
        if usr2 == "p":
            player_2_points += 1
        return f"{player_2} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "r":
        if usr2 == "s":
            player_1_points += 1
        return f"{player_1} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "p":
        if usr2 == "r":
            player_1_points += 1
        return f"{player_1} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "p":
        if usr2 == "s":
            player_2_points += 1
        return f"{player_2} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "s":
        if usr2 == "p":
            player_1_points += 1
        return f"{player_1} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "s":
        if usr2 == "r":
            player_2_points += 1
            return f"{player_2} wins!"


print("Enter hand:\n(R)ock\n(P)aper\n(S)cissors")

while True:
    if play_count < game_limit:
        game_play1 = input(f"{player_1}, enter your hand: ").lower()
        game_play2 = input(f"{player_2}, enter your hand: ").lower()

        print(play(game_play1, game_play2))
        play_count += 1
    elif player_1_points > player_2_points:
        print(f"{player_1} is the winer with {player_1_points} points!"
        print("Game Over")
        break
    else:
        print(f"{player_2} is the winer with {player_2_points} points!"
        print("Game Over")
        break
```

Comment: You should keep that play_count increment part inside your if statement to keep the while loop working correctly.

Comment: Thanks Anus, I updated my post. I was able to fix the code, however now I get a new problem with score count. Now im trying to print a message at the end with the player score, however, Python is not recognizing the player_1_scroe variable because is inside of the function. How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variables player_1_points and player_2_points  outside the function.

Use keyword 'global' to change the variables inside the function.

```
player_1 = input("Enter player 1 Name: ").capitalize()
player_2 = input("Enter player 2 Name: ").capitalize()
game_limit = int(input("Enter how many hands you want to play"))
play_count = 0
player_1_points = 0
player_2_points = 0

def play(usr1, usr2):
    global player_1_points
    global player_2_points
    if usr1 == usr2:
        player_1_points += 1
        player_2_points += 1
        return "Its a Tie!"

    elif usr1 == "r":
        if usr2 == "p":
            player_2_points += 1
        return f"{player_2} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "r":
        if usr2 == "s":
            player_1_points += 1
        return f"{player_1} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "p":
        if usr2 == "r":
            player_1_points += 1
        return f"{player_1} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "p":
        if usr2 == "s":
            player_2_points += 1
        return f"{player_2} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "s":
        if usr2 == "p":
            player_1_points += 1
        return f"{player_1} wins!"

    elif usr1 == "s":
        if usr2 == "r":
            player_2_points += 1
            return f"{player_2} wins!"



print("Enter hand:\n(R)ock\n(P)aper\n(S)cissors")
while True:
    if play_count < game_limit:


        game_play1 = input(f"{player_1}, enter your hand: ").lower()
        game_play2 = input(f"{player_2}, enter your hand: ").lower()

        print(play(game_play1, game_play2))
        play_count += 1
    elif player_1_points > player_2_points:
        print(f"{player_1} is the winer with {player_1_points} points!")
        print("Game Over")
        break
    else:
        print(f"{player_2} is the winer with {player_2_points} points!")
        print("Game Over")
        break
```

Comment: Enjoy yourself with python